# How to use prepopulated database in listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to put together an app that uses a prepopulated SQLite database that when loaded, will populate a list view.  I'm fairly new to android and have been using guides online to help me through.  Using the examples from this site: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I am unsure how to get everything set up to start populating the data into a list view.  Any pointers or examples would really be helpful.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.TestSQLlite/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "TestDatabase";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private final Context myContext;


public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}
@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
   // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
   // to you to create adapters for your views.
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an excellent tutorial on creating and using a database class.  You have to register, but you don't have to verify so you don't have to use real info.

h[ttp://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842)